# How do I fork one child process per hash key?

Tags: perl, fork

I have a hash and when I try to create one child process for each hash key, it is not behaving the way I expect.

Please suggest changes?
**assuming the `$pid` is never less than 0.**

```
foreach $elem(keys %hash)
{
    $pid = fork();

    if ($pid) 
    {
       push @pids, $pid;
       print "in parent $$\n";
    }
    else
    { 
        print "in child $$\n"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok this is done. it just require exit 0 in the child process.THANKS JIMBO for making it readable.

Comment: @RobEarl without exit 0 it will gone on creating child of child processes so i did some experiment and finally landed up using exit 0 after print in child.

Comment: @mkp Welcome to Stack Overflow! If an answer solves your problem, the way to say thank you is to click the upvote arrow and also the green checkmark to accept the answer.

Comment: Also note that your assumption that `$pid` never indicates failure is a dangerous one. In Perl, `fork` returns the undefined value on failure. Always, *always*, **always** check return values from system calls to OS services such as `fork`, `open`, `exec`, and so on. Otherwise you risk running into strange bugs when your assumptions fail.

Comment: @Greg Bacon sir i solved the problem on my own without help and before anybody replied except you but thanks alot for making it readable and i will keep in mind your suggestion

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When executing the child, don't forget to exit, otherwise the child process also will execute the fork, and the total number of created processes will be higher than expected.

```
foreach $elem(keys %hash)
{
    $pid = fork();

    if ($pid) 
    {
       push @pids, $pid;
       print "in parent $$\n";
    }
    else
    { 
        print "in child $$\n"; 
        exit(0); #<--- add this or exec external program
    }
}
```

Comment: `fork` returns the undefined value on failure, but that case is being lumped in with 0 being returned to child processes.

Comment: i have already commented above about adding and that solved my problem. But thanks alot.

Answer (score 1):

You should check to see if the `fork()` worked:

```
foreach $elem(keys %hash)
{
    $pid = fork();

    if( ! defined( $pid )){
        die "could not fork\n";
    }

    if ($pid) 
    {
       push @pids, $pid;
       print "in parent $$\n";
    }
    else
    { 
        print "in child $$\n"; 
    }
}
```